# Rterm.exe error in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using R 3.2.2 and RStudio 0.99.486 (latest version) under Windows 7 SP1 64 bit. I always get an error when I start RStudio:

```
the procedure entry point vsnprintf could not be 
located in the dynamic link library R.dll
```

[image]

But I don't get any errors when I directly start R 3.2.2.

The R installed into C:/ProgramFiles/R/R-3.2.2/ (not the default path) and don't have other versions of R. RStudio is setup to use the installed R.

Except I get an error in RStudio, all my R codes can run in RGUI and RStudio.

Thanks for any suggestions to solve this annoying problem.

My session information

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2
> .libPaths()
```

Comment: Doesn't look programming related to me and thus probably OT. You should probably update RStudio or contact their support.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg. The lastest RStudio has the same problem. Will contact the developer.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with R3.3.1 64bit under Windows 7. `RTerm.exe` error is `The procedure entry point MPI_COMM_SPLIT_TYPE could not be located in the dynamic link library msmpi.dll`. The error pops up shortly after starting RStudio, but once acknowledged, RStudio seems to proceed fine. If I switch to R3.3.1 32 bit, then there is no error.